# Receiving data from sendBroadcast()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to read data carried by sendBroadcast() method. I have this code written already and I want to present `message` in `TextView`

```
message = incoming.readUTF();
String[] incomingTable = new String[5];
incomingTable[0] = message;
incomingTable[1] = message;
Intent actual = new Intent(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
actual.putExtra("Message", String.format("%s", incomingTable[1]));
getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(actual);
```

**What I want to achieve:** I want to set the text of `TextView` in `MainActivity` to `message` string. What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are send `massage` to a `BroadcastReceiver` but, if I understood, you are asking how get it in an activity!

Comment: Are the code you posted in `MainActivity`?

Comment: No. It is in `public void run()` method of `private class AcceptThread extends Thread`

Comment: Have you access to the `TextView` in that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainActivity declare and define the broadcatReceiver:

```
UpdTextViewReceiver updTextViewReceiver;
public class UpdTextViewReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(EXTRA_MESSAGE)){  
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("Message")
            MainActivity.updateTextView(message);
        }
   }

}  

private void updateTextView(String message){

    //Update the TextView here
}
```

Instantiate the receiver in onCreate:

```
updTextViewReceiver = new UpdTextViewReceiver();
```

Register the BoadcastReceiver in onResume

```
registerReceiver(updTextViewReceiver, new IntentFilter(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
```

UnRegister the BoadcastReceiver in onPause

```
unregisterReceiver(updTextViewReceiver);
```

Done!